# AgGrid custom template for no data is not working correctly

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am trying to update overlayNoRowsTemplate in case no data exists for table. But its not working correctly i have used below code

**.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  rowData = []
  columnDefs = [
    {
      headerName: "ID",
      field: "id",
    },
    {
      headerName: "Value",
      field: "value",
    },

  ];
  overlayNoRowsTemplate = `This is Custom Message for no data</br> <span class="error">Login After some time</span>`

}
```

.html

```
<ag-grid-angular style="width: 100%; height: 120px;" class="ag-theme-fresh" 
    [rowData]="rowData"
        [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [overlayNoRowsTemplate]="overlayNoRowsTemplate">
    </ag-grid-angular>
```

Only half message is being shown **This is Custom Message for no data**

Below is the sample code link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-angular-8awpde?file=app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`overlayNoRowsTemplate` only works if you provide a parent element

This [works](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-angular-uqzlbu?file=app/app.component.ts)

```js
overlayNoRowsTemplate = `<span>
      This is Custom Message for no data
      </br>
      <span class="error">Login After some time</span>
   </span>`
```

But this only show the first element, in this case the one contains one

```js
overlayNoRowsTemplate = `<span>one</span><span>two</span>`
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. have you found some documentation for this ?

Comment: No documentation that I know of. But I agree this behavior should be documented

Answer (score 1):

Try enveloping the message in a paragraph tag for example:

`overlayNoRowsTemplate = "<p>This is Custom Message for no data</br><span class="error">Login After some time</span></p>"`

And go read a bit about span element ;)
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp

Comment: Thanks for your answer but fact is like if i change span to div still it will not work. Your case is working because overlayNoRowsTemplate needs a top level wrapper